# How does equipment scale regarding sidekicking and WvW?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In PVE, in the process of leveling up, you find better armor and weapons, and those have better / higher stats.

Assuming you're level 50 with appropiate-level armor, what stats are given to you when you're scaled *down*? Does the stats given by the equipment remain? How does it scale?

Now, opposite case in WvW: since you use your PVE equipment but you're scaled *up*, how does the equipment scales? Having a full 80-set with appropiate stats is much superior to a lvl 50 character with appropiate-level equipment? How does that work?

Comment: The downscaling is explained, and the upscaling to some level, but that answers the question for base stats, not for weapons. In the question, there's a comment that asks basically the same thing: What if I have a +100 STR weapon? What happens with those stats? If I go to WvW, are those stats scaled up, too?

Comment: Your 'base' stats are comprised of your level/traits as well as all the bonuses from your armour/weapon - it's not calculated separately, so your question is answered.